# read input from a file and append that values to variables using bash

Tags: bash, unix, sh

```
#!/bin/bash
 
while IFS= read -r line 
do 
    echo $line
done < test.txt
```

where test.txt is a input file in here which includes following data:

```
city
location
name
age
occupation
```

Comment: i need to assign variable to each names  in test.txt and when i try to echo those variables it should print the names

Answer (score 1):

How about making the first letter Capital for the variable name.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf -v "${line^}" '%s' "$line"
done < file.txt

printf '%s\n' "$City" "$Location" "$Name" "$Age" "$Occupation"
```

Replace the

```
printf -v "${line^}" '%s' "$line"
```

With

```
printf -v "$line" '%s' "$line"
```

To make the variable name same as the value but beware of special characters special to the shell. Also there is a rule about variable names since not all characters/strings are allowed to be in it. This post has some insight about variable names convention: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428880/list-of-acceptable-initial-characters-for-a-bash-variable

---

Or an associative array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  declare -A values["$line"]="$line"
done < file.txt

declare -p values
```

---

Output

```
declare -A values=([city]="city" [location]="location" [occupation]="occupation" [age]="age" [name]="name" )
```

Comment: thanks for this but can you help me with solution to where the input file has n lines and when i try to echo the variable then only it should print the values

Comment: You mean the variable name is the same as the value?

Comment: no it does not necessarily needs to be the same but needs to assign variable to each line/name and when i try to echo that variable it should print the name

Comment: Then my solution should work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution i  will try with this one